# replace MTA with something not email related

Tags: cron, email, output, mail-transport-agent

What I try to achieve is to send all my server logs, errors, crontab outputs etc. with something like telegram or signal. I am locking for a MTA with can handle a different backend and is still compatible with the overall Linux MTA concept.

So **without** fiddling with scripts and crontabs I would like all output, which would be transfered by mail to be transfered by a custom backend.

Is there a way to change the MTA backend?

What I found so far is [ntfy](https://github.com/dschep/ntfy), but it's just a script to set different notification backends, I think there is a missing puzzle piece between the script and a proper MTA.

Thanks for the input

Comment: https://github.com/dYalib/Mail2Telegram ?

Comment: seems to go in the right direction. Thank you, I will do same research.